# Cannot open new excel file or select an open excel file when macro in break mode

Tags: excel, vba

I run the macro step by step, in this moment I can't open a new workbook or view another open workbook. this issue occured after I close workbook in immediate window of VBE. Could you know how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: While VBA is in Break mode all other activity is suspended. This is so that you can examine the current state of your project. It doesn't need "fixing". In addition, while you type commands in the Immediate pane you can't move the code cursor, meaning VBE's normal activity is also suspended. Return to the VBE (by clicking in that pane) is likely to end the Break mode if VB misses the workbook you closed.

Comment: Thanks your comment. what I want to say is, I can open a another workbook or select an opened workbook before this issue occured. But now I can't.  The reason may be is I use "workbooks.close" in immediate pane to close a opened workbook. After that the issue occured when the macro in break mode.

Comment: reboot your  PC. Your code probably has something like screenupdating or displayalerts turned off, an error occurs in the background and nothing's working after first fail.

Comment: I reboot my PC everyday but the error still there. I agree with you that it is like a background error. but I don't know how to fix it.